# Can an object belong to a class be assigned to a variable of a type that is a subclass without casting?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have 3 questions and I would appreciate it if someone can explain it to me.

First of all,

Can an object belong to a class be assigned to a variable of a type that is a subclass without casting? If the answer is yes is casting required when assigning the object to a superclass? or did I just flipped them over?

Secondly, is it right that in an interface a method with a single parameter can accept as the argument value for that parameter objects from many different classes that are not related by inheritance? I will say yes to this question because the interface can be extended by different classes but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Finally, are methods inside a public class automatically defined public? or is it suppose to be defined as package?

Comment: I can tell you the answer to the last question: no, methods that are in a public class are not necessarily public. Could you be more clear on the other two?

Comment: What have you tried? It would have been easier to write some Java code and run the compiler to answer these questions. Also, it's [encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) to ask a single question per post. That helps other people with the same question to find their answer more easily via search engines.

Comment: Remember you are casting a **reference**, not an object. Changing the type of a reference doesn't touch the object it points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get what you meant in your second question, so I'll post an answer to your first and third question, hoping that you will edit your question and rephrase your second question.

1) No, it's not possible. Otherwise, the following would be possible:

```
SomeInterface object1 = new Class1ImplementingInterface ();
Class2ImplementingInterface object2 = object1;    // Won't compile
```

This above piece of code doesn't compile. However, if you change it to:

```
SomeInterface object1 = new Class1ImplementingInterface ();
Class2ImplementingInterface object2 = (Class2ImplementingInterface) object1;    // Compiles, but will crash at runtime
```

It will compile, but it will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime. However, it is possible to assign an object of a specific class to an object of a parent class/interface without casting it. For instance:

```
Class2ImplementingInterface object2 = new Class2ImplementingInterface ();
SomeInterface object1 = object2;    // OK
```

2) Your question doesn't specify if the parameter's type is an interface or not, which makes a difference. Assuming that you asked specificly for interfaces, then yes, a method with a parameter will accept any instance of the parameter's type, or any subtype. E.g.

```
public void someMethod (SomeInterface parameter) {
    // Implementation
}
```

The above code will accept an object of any class that implement `SomeInterface`. However, if the parameter's type is a class, then only objects of the same class, or anyclass extending this base class, will be accepted.

3) No, the default access for members, constructors and methods is `package private`, meaning that only classes in the same package will have access to those. You have to specify the `public` access modifier on members you wish to expose.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.
For the second question, I meant is it right that in an interface a method with a single parameter can accept as the argument value for that parameter objects from many different classes that are not related by inheritance?

Comment: So casting is required when assigning variables to either subclass or superclass, right?

Comment: Informative. Thanks. Regarding 1st question, i wanted to confirm, if we can assign child object to its parent object?

Answer (score 1):

1. No.  When you have a variable of type `A`, anything you assign to it must **be** an `A`.  A reference of `A`'s supertype `B` does not necessarily refer to an 'A'.  It's the other way around.
2. I think what you're asking is this: if a method accepts a parameter of a type that is an **interface**, will it accept instances of various classes that implement this interface, with no other (inheritance) relationship between those classes?  The answer is yes: as long as they implement that interface, they are legal parameters.
3. No, by default they have **package visibility**.